# Draw vector line from angle data in attribute table

Tags: qgis

Im new to QGIS. I am making maps and sea charts from different WFS sources. I am wondering if there is a way to draw vector lines from a lighthouse using the angle data that's in the attribute table with code looking up the values and position if the lighthouse. Like in this picture. Right now I just have a small coloured SVG pointing in the directions of the corresponding light.

[image: Vector lines from lighthouse]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a geometry generator style for this. Go to layer properties -> symbology and add a new geometry generator to your points:

[image]

Now use an expression like this:

```
make_line($geometry,project($geometry,25,"angle"))
```

It creates a line, starting from your point and ending at a point in 25 crs units, projected in the angle from your attribute table. `"angle"` is the name of the field in the attribute table containing a numerical value with your desired angle.

> `project()` Returns a point projected from a start point *(first argument)* using a
> distance *(second argument)*, a bearing (azimuth) *(third argument)* and an elevation *(fourth, optional argument)* in radians. Azimuth is in radians clockwise, where 0 corresponds to north.

`make_line()` then connects the start-point (`$geometry`) with the projected end-point.

Comment: And if you want to reproduce the yellow coloured area, the `wedge_buffer` function would be a good approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your expertise. That did exactly what I wanted. I now have some CRS issues I believe that I haven't figured out yet. The vectors are off by about 3 degrees, and that increases if I move 200km to the west.

Comment: @cmholm yes, this sounds like an crs issue. I can only suggest to try reprojecting your data to a crs which fits better into your area of interest. If you struggle with that, feel free to open a [new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about that.